# CSS Background Image/Movie URL?

Tags: html, css, movie

I have noticed that GIF's are not really compatible in all browsers so instead I have been using movies. Which has been working find until now. I have a website with a background image that is written in css. I had a feeling this would not work but I tried linking the movie like I would a image and it did not even show up. Below is the html and css.

html

```
 <section id="slider">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="block">
          <h1 class="animated fadeInUp">Need a Network?</h1>
          <p class="animated fadeInUp">Then you are in the right place. We can help Design, Setup, Configure, and Maintain a network that fits your exact needs.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

css

```
#slider {
background: url("../img/") no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: 10% 0%;
padding: 200px 0 280px 0;
position: relative;
}
#slider:before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: linear-gradient(to left, #8b86a3, #322e40);
opacity: 0.8;
}
#slider .block {
color: #E3E3E4;
}
#slider .block h1 {
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-weight: 100;
font-size: 45px;
line-height: 60px;
letter-spacing: 10px;
padding-bottom: 45px;
}
#slider .block p {
font-size: 23px;
line-height: 40px;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
letter-spacing: 3px; 
}
```

From my understanding, linking the video is not going to happen so what would be another option? How would I go about this? I need to text that is there now to still show up and for the movie to be opaque. If I need to make the actual movie itself opaque I can do that. Thanks

Can view website all together [here](http://gggggg.000webhostapp.com/test/)

Comment: You mean, the `video` or the `embed` tag?

Comment: Not sure what you mean... @LloydDominic

Comment: background: url("../img/") no-repeat;

Comment: i need to link the movie but it doesnt work

Comment: The `background` tag is only used for background colors or background images.  If you want to place a video in your webpage, you would have to use the tags, `video`, `embed`, or `iframe`. (Pick just one!  :) )

Comment: can that be put into the css?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean ... Where do you want to put the movie / video?

Comment: I would like the video to be behind the "need a network?" part which is linked through the css in the background: url ("/img/") no-repeat;

Comment: but when i link the video it docent show up

Comment: It's because the `background` tag can only handle colors (`background: white`), or images (`background: url("/img/image.jpg")`), not videos.  Therefore, you would have to use `video`, `embed`, or `iframe` tags that can handle videos very well!

Comment: yea, where do i put the video or embed or iframe tag and still have the text and other css elements work correctly

Comment: "I have noticed that GIF's are not really compatible in all browsers"  Well... that's not true.

Comment: If you need video as a background, you can achieve this by using `video` tag in `html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a video behind the "need a network" part, by using this code:

> I replaced the video, and used the JavaScript code to "autoplay" the video!
>
> If you think the video can autoplay without JavaScript, remove it!
>
> ---
>
> I also replaced the `iframe` tag, with the `video` tag.
>
> You can replace the video, by changing the `src=""` attribute on the `<source>` tag, inside the `<video>` tag.

```js
function playVideo() {
document.getElementsByClassName('video')[0].play();
}
```

```css
.video {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: -2;
object-fit: fill;
}
#slider {
/* Removed the background tags, since there are no image placed in the url of the background tag */
/*background: url("../img/") no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: 10% 0%;*/
padding: 200px 0 280px 0;
position: relative;
}
#slider:before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: linear-gradient(to left, #8b86a3, #322e40);
opacity: 0.8;
z-index: -1;
}
#slider .block {
color: #E3E3E4;
}
#slider .block h1 {
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-weight: 100;
font-size: 45px;
line-height: 60px;
letter-spacing: 10px;
padding-bottom: 45px;
}
#slider .block p {
font-size: 23px;
line-height: 40px;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
letter-spacing: 3px; 
}
```

```html
<body onload="playVideo()">
<section id="slider">
  <video class="video" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="block">
          <h1 class="animated fadeInUp">Need a Network?</h1>
          <p class="animated fadeInUp">Then you are in the right place. We can help Design, Setup, Configure, and Maintain a network that fits your exact needs.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
</body>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks I will try tomorrow and will let you know how it works @Lloyddominic

Comment: This is what I'm saying! ...  :)

Comment: Anyways, you could just replace your video,  y changing the `src` attribute in the `iframe` tag.

Comment: Hello, it did not seem to work. It is still blank like it was before

Answer (score 0):

You can check out how to add a video [Tutorial](https://tutorialehtml.com/en/html-tutorial-embed-video/)

***Edit***: Edited fiddle

```js
var $vid = $('video','#container');
var $msg = $('#custom-message'); 
$msg.css({
    top:$vid.offset().top + (($vid.height()/2) - ($msg.height()/2)),
    left:$vid.offset().left + (($vid.width()/2) - ($msg.width()/2))
});
```

```css
video {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}

#custom-message {
  position: absolute;
  color: rgb(230, 200, 200);
  z-index: 1;
}

#slider {
  background: url("../img/") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: 10% 0%;
  padding: 200px 0 280px 0;
  position: relative;
}

#slider:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #8b86a3, #322e40);
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#slider .block {
  color: #E3E3E4;
}

#slider .block h1 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 45px;
  line-height: 60px;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 45px;
}

#slider .block p {
  font-size: 23px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" align="center">

  <section id="slider">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
      <div id="container" align="center">
        <video width="640" height="320" autoplay>
          <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
        <div id="custom-message">
          Need a Network?</div>
        <div id="custom-message">Then you are in the right place. We can help Design, Setup, Configure, and Maintain a network that fits your exact needs.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </section>
```

Comment: I see but how would i encooperate this and still have the css work properly